# How to post data to a website that immediately redirects you to another one

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to batch work on this [website](http://rna.physics.missouri.edu/vfold3D/index.html), but it doesn't provide a batch mode for the user, so I am thinking about using python to submit tasks.

I am not really familiar with web-scraping by python. I watched several videos on Youtube and also checked many posts here, and I can successfully do log-in in some website by clicking the mouse on the browser, check the elements, go to the Network and see what data I should put in in the POST method.

However, this website, after you submit a task, will immediately open a new url for you, and there is no sign of any POST in the Network flow. I have already spent hours trying but still don't know how to tackle this site. Can anyone help me with this?

Here in the data dictionary I have erased the email, and you can put in your own email address. If you successfully post a task to this server, you should get an email informing you when it's finished.

```py
import requests

url1 = 'http://rna.physics.missouri.edu/vfold3D/index.html'

sequence = 'UCGGACCAUCAGGAGAAAUCCAAUGGAAAACAGGGAAACCCUAAAAGCAAUUUUGGAAGUUUAAAACCGA'
bps = '.((((((((..(((....))).)))).((((.(((...))).((((....))))....))))....))))'
jobname = 'A trial'

data = {}
data['sequence'] = sequence
data['bps'] = bps
data['jobname'] = jobname
data['email'] = ''  # give an email address to receive the result

req1 = requests.post(url1, data=data)

print(req1.status_code)
```

The status code is 200, but I receive no email, so I don't think I successfully post anything to it.

As I have said, I don't know what should be the correct data that should be sent to the server, since I didn't see any trace of POST in the Network flow, and I never learned anything about html and so know nothing about the structure of this website...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print your response `req1.contents` using `jobname = 'A trial'` parameter, you get an error page that saying there's spaces/invalid chars in job name.

```
Please wait...<br>
<br>
Your input jobname: <br>
A trial
<br>
<br>
<font color="red" size="3">contains non-alphanumeric characters.</font><br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

You must remove those spaces.

This works and gives you the URL to check the results:

```
import re
import requests

server_url = 'http://rna.physics.missouri.edu/vfold3D/3D_run.pl'

sequence = 'UCGGACCAUCAGGAGAAAUCCAAUGGAAAACAGGGAAACCCUAAAAGCAAUUUUGGAAGUUUAAAACCGA'
bps = '.((((((((..(((....))).)))).((((.(((...))).((((....))))....))))....))))'
jobname = 'Atrial'

data = {
    'sequence': sequence,
    'bps': bps,
    'jobname': jobname,
    'email': ''
}

res = requests.post(server_url, 
                    data=data, 
                    headers={'referer': 'http://rna.physics.missouri.edu/vfold3D/index.html'})
result_url = re.search('<META HTTP-EQUIV=refresh CONTENT="0;URL=([^"]+)', res.text).group(1)
print(result_url)
```

output:

```
http://rna.physics.missouri.edu/OUTPUT/3D_Atrial.E6SY.html
```

You can then visit that URL and get `.pdb` file.

```
import requests
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin

res =  requests.get('http://rna.physics.missouri.edu/OUTPUT/3D_Atrial.E6SY.html')
pdb_path = re.search('<a href="(.*\.pdb)">', res.text).group(1)
pdb_url = urljoin(res.url, pdb_path)
print(pdb_url)
```

output:

```
http://rna.physics.missouri.edu/OUTPUT/3D_Atrial.E6SY.3d_struct.pdb
```

---

**Note:** Since these pages don't look like they will be redesigned anytime soon, and have relatively simple structure, using `re` to scrape off some URL is perfectly OK. But using BeautifulSoup or another HTML parser is the proper way.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for the help! Can I ask a side question why I can't see any trace of POST in the Network flow after I click the submit?

Comment: It shows up actually. When you submit the form and a new page pops up, switch to that tab, open the open Developer Tools's Network tab. Then refresh the page, it'll ask you if you want to resubmit the form, confirm. You'll see an empty POST request. It will stay empty until the server accepts it, then you'll be able to see its details.

Comment: That's so tricky (for a rookie like me). I indeed checked the popped-up page, but saw nothing in the Network. I never thought about refreshing the page to see the POST request. By the way, what if there is still no POST after you refresh the page (I don't know whether that's possible), then how to figure out what data to put in (for this website I figured it out by checking the source code of the page and looked for the input) and what headers to add? Here it is obvious that the referer should be the original site, but what if a more complicated situation?

Comment: It has to be somewhere. Remember to tick _Persist logs_ (or something similar) checkbox to keep the logs, then sift through it using the filters. You'll find it on the source page or the pop up page like this one.

Comment: Got it. Great thanks for your patience and detailed explanations!